# CoreLocation not getting actual position, but from "simulation location" in schemes

Tags: ios, core-location

I am having problems with Core Location with an iphone 5c IOS 8.

If I leave on "Edit Scheme/Options" "Allow Location Simulation" checked with anyone location, in the method 'didUpdateLocations' always return the position always that are called, and

> **never return the current position.**

**This problem occurs on the simulator and the iphone 5c IOS 8.**

If I leave 'none' in the list of locations, or uncheck "allow location simulation", the method 'didFailWithError' return an error

**Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self startStandardUpdates];

}

- (void)startStandardUpdates {

    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; 
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }

    if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {

    CLLocation *d = [locations objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"%@",d);
}
```

The returns are:

**2015-02-23 17:51:34.663 appRadar[434:27082] Erro: Error Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)"** (Allow simulation location unchecked)

or

**2015-02-23 18:10:05.024 appRadar[444:30091] <-22.90353930,-43.20958690> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 23/02/15 18:10:05 Horário Padrão de Brasília** (Rio de Janeiro Selected)

Comment: And what is the problem? It looks to me like this is the default behaviour.

Comment: How I get the real current position?

Comment: Please update your post so that it clearly contains a sentence which is a question with question-mark at the end. Also add information what are the results for this in simulator..and on real ios device.